# Sharepoint 2010 workflow task custom content type

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, task, content-type

I'm trying to create workflow(state machine)  with particular content type task, and receiving "An error has occurred in [workflow name] " error in workflow history, which is absolutely no informative, in this case I have no idea what happened and where is my mistake.

More details :

- I have created VS project for task with custom content type and its forms, and deployed it.
- I have created VS project for state machine workflow.
  in the Elements.xml set up **TaskListContentTypeId**

My Elements.xml

```
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <Workflow
         Name="Pre-Award Approval Workflow"
         Description="Pre-Award Approval Workflow"
         Id="33ad7f25-b86f-43e8-86d8-300e92891227"
         CodeBesideClass="Pre_Award_Approval_Worflow.Workflow.Workflow"
         TaskListContentTypeId="0x0100d7d89499b9234bde9a67bfb11db5ce64"
         CodeBesideAssembly="$assemblyname$">
        <Categories/>
        <MetaData>
          <AssociationCategories>List</AssociationCategories>
          <StatusPageUrl>_layouts/WrkStat.aspx</StatusPageUrl>
        </MetaData>
      </Workflow>
    </Elements>
```

The workflow adjusted on new item create event.

When I create a new item of my list I received error on workflow history **"An error has occurred in [workflow name] "**

To find in which step error has occurred I set up before and after each workflow step **LogToHistoryListActivity** and found out that error occurred in **createTask** , but when I try-catched whole **crteateTask_Invoking** function there is no exception occured.

When I took away  **TaskListContentTypeId="0x0100d7d89499b9234bde9a67bfb11db5ce64"** from Element.xml there is no error, but workflow created task with default content type which is no good for me.

Where is my mistake?

I will be happy even if anybody can give me advice in which way I should investigate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the syntax for the content type id is correct?

Comment: @jan-jouke-tjalsma I've obtained it from **Schema.xml** <br/> Why You have asked about it, do You have guesses?

Comment: To be honest I've never coded a workflow like this before, it's just that GUID's usually have the curly brackets and other ID's tend to be shorter. But you are right, it's a bit of a guess.

Comment: @jan-jouke-tjalsma That is the problem, I don't know how to develop workflow  exactly )). May be You could give me some explanation from You experience of workflow coding?

Comment: It seems the syntax for The content type is fine. Maybe the content type you are specifying should inherit from the Workflow Task content type? It should then start with 0x010801. Yours inherits from custom list if I'm correct. Perhaps the workflow expects certain columns in the content type that are not there when you inherit from custom list. You could probably test this by putting the default workflow task content type id there.

Comment: To get more SharePoint experts looking into this you should consider posting your question into the SharePoint stackexchange site.

Comment: @jan-jouke-tjalsma   About **It should then start with 0x010801.**  - Yes, seems You are right, after done some test I became to the same.

Comment: I don't know if my way is correct, because I could find any documentation to prove it, but it works.  Below some point that should or shouldn't be done for coding custom workflow task content type

Comment: 1) There is necessary to create Custom Content type inherited from **Workflow Tasks**

Comment: 2) Don't create Custom List Definition , Content Type is Enough

Comment: 3) Content Type ID should starts with  **ID="0x010801...."**

Comment: 4) To link particular content type for the **all** workflow tasks need to add to workflow  Elements.xml  **TaskListContentTypeId="0x010801....."**

Comment: If you add this as an answer you can accept it and people will be able to use your work.

Answer (score 0):

After more deeply digging in this issue I found the best solution where well described this topic. It is a book  - **SharePoint 2010 as a Development Platform - 2010**, particularly  in **Chapter -16** subject **Deploying Workflows**. I hope its will help for someone.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem with the code

The problem is that the content type starting with `0x0100`  is not a valid option for the workflow option `TaskListContentTypeId`.

### Solution

To make a workflow use a non-default content type for workflow tasks the content type must inherit from the default Task list content type. The resulting content type ID starts with `0x010801`.

So in your Elements.xml you should have

```
TaskListContentTypeId="0x010801....."
```

More information in the book ["*SharePoint 2010 as a Development Platform*"](https://books.google.nl/books/about/SharePoint_2010_as_a_Development_Platfor.html?id=4lKnn9ZzG1AC&redir_esc=y) (pp. 947-1034) by Joerg Krause et al, 2010.

### Credits

Jamal Ulb for asking this interesting question and sharing his testresults leading to the answer you are reading now.